# How to run Selenium webdriver on Tomcat server?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, tomcat

I have Tomcat server running in Eclipse IDE. Whole set up is on windows server 2012. When I run the selenium webdriver from my local computer without the Tomcat server, it works fine. **But it's not working on Tomcat server**. I am not seeing any error too. Please find my code below. I have tried to put some logs to see the flow. There are no traces after "111111". I am not using selenium server standalone jar because of Tomcat webserver. Is it possible to run selenium tests on Tomcat server?

```
private void uploadDBIFileInDSS(String csvFileString) throws BillingUserException{
    HomeController.logger.debug("Start");
    WebDriver driver = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("111111");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "XXXXX/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("XXXXXXX");
        System.out.println("222222");
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("IDToken1"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("IDToken2"));
        username.sendKeys("XXXXX");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        password.sendKeys("XXXXXX");
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.name("Submit"));
        loginButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'XXXXX')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'XXXX')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'XXXX')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement attachFileButton = driver.findElement(By.name("upfile"));

        attachFileButton.sendKeys("XXXXXX");

        Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("reason")));

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        dropdown.selectByValue("Misc");

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.findElement(By.name("Submit")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'XXXX')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();


    }catch(Exception exp) {
        driver.close();
        exp.printStackTrace();
        throw new BillingUserException(BillingUserException.XXXXXXX);
    }
    HomeController.logger.debug("End");

}
```

Comment: You should try to run Tomcat locally on your machine so that you can reach Your webpages; that way you can interact with it as  a normal webpage; I suppose you're running Tomcat in EclipseIDE right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try remote web driver instead of chrome web driver.

I guess current problem with your code is, you have to import chrome.exe and chrome web driver in WEB-INF/lib.

Hope it helps.